# How to create Mixins for Polymer.AppLocalizeBehavior

Tags: localization, mixins, behavior

How to create mixins for Polymer.AppLocalizeBehavior for Polymer 2.x?

I am using Redux mixins using following syntax:

```
 class MyCreateAccount extends ReduxBehavior(Polymer.Element) {..}
```

I need to add Polymer.AppLocalizeBehavior to my class declaration and need help in creating the required mixin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the class-based syntax you can simulate element multiple inheritance of class mixins with something.

For example if you've created a redux store file like this

```
<...your redux store content...>
const store = Redux.createStore((state = {}, action) => state)
const ReduxMixin = PolymerRedux(store)
```

You can import that file and bind elements using redux mixin wrap the mixin behaviors which you can include your behaviors inside.

```
class MyCreateAccount extends ReduxMixin(Polymer.mixinBehaviors([Polymer.AppLocalizeBehavior], Polymer.Element)) { .. }
```

or you can use the Polymer 2 hybrid behaviours as mixins by extending Polymer.mixinBehaviors([behaviors], superclass) as below

```
class MyCreateAccount extends Polymer.mixinBehaviors([Polymer.AppLocalizeBehavior, ReduxBehavior], Polymer.Element) { .. }
```